# Dúvida na publicação de site feito em asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Após fazer a publicação para uma pasta local no computador, subir os arquivos on-line é me gerou o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem que deixar ele exibir o erro mesmo se estiver publicado ou botar um log para pegar o erro... Essa mensagem aí só diz que deu um erro lá...

Comment: @sim, deu um erro, mais como eu ajusto este erro?

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o seguinte ao seu `web.config` e publique novamente:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

O erro de verdade será exibido.

Comment: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -532462766.


Show Detailed Compiler Output:


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274

Comment: Então, este é o erro de verdade.

Comment: Estou compilando novamente é subindo os arquivos, vou ver o que acontece